# R: regex to capture all instances after a given character

Tags: r, regex, pcre, backreference

Given string `ab cd  ; ef  gh ij`, how do I remove all spaces after the first space after `;`, i.e. `ab cd  ; efghij`? I tried using `\K` but can't get it to work completely.

```
test = 'ab cd  ; ef  gh ij'
gsub('(?<=; )[^ ]+\\K +','',test,perl=T)
# "ab cd  ; efgh ij"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) gsubfn** Using `gsubfn` in the gsubfn package, here is a one-liner that only uses simple regular expressions. It inputs the capture group into the indicated function (expressed in formula notation) and replaces the match with the output of the function.

```
library(gsubfn)

gsubfn("; (.*)", ~ paste(";", gsub(" ", "", x)), test)
## [1] "ab cd  ; efghij"
```

**2) gsub**  This uses a pattern consisting of space not immediately preceeded by a semicolon and not followed anywhere in the remainder of the string by a semicolon.

```
gsub("(?<!;) (?!.*; )", "", test, perl = TRUE)
## [1] "ab cd  ; efghij"
```

**3) regexpr/substring** This finds he position of the semicolon and then uses `substring` to break it into two and replace the spaces with `gsub` finally pasting it back together.

```
ix <- regexpr(";", test)
paste(substring(test, 1, ix), gsub(" ", "", substring(test, ix + 2)))
## [1] "ab cd  ; efghij"
```

**4) read.table** This is similar to (3) but uses `read.table` to break the input into two fields.

```
with(read.table(text = test, sep = ";", as.is = TRUE), paste0(V1, "; ", gsub(" ", "", V2)))
## [1] "ab cd  ; efghij"
```

Answer (score 3):

I am sure there is a regex solution (which I hope someone posts), but here is a non-regex solution that relies on the semi-colon being consistent. You can adapt it if there are multiple separators. Hope it help!

```
> # Split the string on the semi-colon (assumes semi-colon is consistent)
> split <- strsplit(c("ab cd  ; ef  gh ij", "abcd e f ; gh ij k"), ";")
> 
> # Extract elements separately
> pre_semicolon <- sapply(split, `[`, 1)
> post_semicolon <- sapply(split, `[`, 2)
> 
> # Remove all spaces from everything after the semi-colon
> post_semicolon <- gsub("[[:space:]]", "", post_semicolon)
> 
> # Paste them back together with a semi-colon and a space
> paste(pre_semicolon, post_semicolon, sep = "; ")
[1] "ab cd  ; efghij"  "abcd e f ; ghijk"
```